# LInux Mint not recognizing/mounting 160 GB HDD

Tags: linux, mount, hard-disk

I am not sure how to get it to mount. 
This is what I get for `sudo fdisk -l`

```
         WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


         Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
         255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
         Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
         Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
         I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
         Disk identifier: 0x00000000

         Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
         /dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
         Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

         Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160000000000 bytes
         255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19452 cylinders, total 312500000 sectors
         Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
         Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
         I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
         Disk identifier: 0xb8ed5093
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your second HDD (160GB) is NTFS

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb  /mnt/
```

Is there an error when you run this command?

Comment: NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?